# How to add additional info to stderr output when bash script calls another application

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, stderr

On Ubuntu, I have a bash script that runs an application.

When that app seg faults, I get some info in std err, e.g.

```
/usr/local/foo/script.sh: line 21: 494382 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) appplication_name_and_arguments_here
```

Std err is being redirected to a file, which is then going into a log monitoring system.

What I'd like to do is augment the stderr content with more helpful info when this happens, e.g. some environment variables, and a timestamp.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting an ERR trap in `script.sh`.  Try putting this close to the top of it as a start:

```
set -o errtrace

trap err_trap ERR

function err_trap
{
    printf 'ERR trap:\n' >&2
    printf '    PATH=%s\n' "$PATH" >&2
    printf '    PWD=%s\n' "$PWD" >&2
    printf '    date: %s\n' "$(date)" >&2

    exit 1
}
```

That's *very* rough and ready, but hopefully you will be able to enhance it to do what you want.

- See the [trap](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap) section in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for information about `trap`.
- See [Mysterious LINENO in bash trap ERR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6928946/4154375) for (somewhat buried) examples of potentially useful things that you can do with an `ERR` trap.
- See [What does `set -o errtrace` do in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25378845/4154375) for an explanation of the `set -o errtrace`.